# "In thrall to" vs "in the thrall of"

Tags: idioms, articles

If you are **in thrall to** someone or something, or **in the thrall of** someone or something, he, she, or it has a lot of power to control you.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://If%20you%20are%20in%20thrall%20to%20someone%20or%20something,%20or%20in%20the%20thrall%20of%20someone%20or%20something,%20he,%20she,%20or%20it%20has%20a%20lot%20of%20power%20to%20control%20you:%20Her%20love%20for%20him%20was%20like%20a%20madness,%20and%20she%20was%20completely%20in%20i)

Why  "in thrall to" but "in ***the*** thrall of"?

Comment: You can also be *enthralled **by*** someone/something, but that's rarely used with the literal ***enslaved*** sense today. Preposition and article use is somewhat arbitrary/idiomatic, so I doubt you'll get an "answer" to this one.

Comment: I would say the difference lies in the master<->slave dynamic, that is, *in thrall to* suggests the thrall is much weaker than in *in the thrall of*. The reason for this could be that the definite article **the** adds more *gravitas* to the power the master holds, and the **of** emphasises that the control is indeed in the hands of the master, while **to** from the first phrase is weaker in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

THRALL has traversed a lot from its Old English meaning of a slave/a servant/ a captive. Presently THRALL goes to mean that only in a figurative way. Now we mean by thrall

- A person on moral and mental
  servitude.(We are in the thrall of
  our mad flight.)
- A state of servitude or submission
  ( in thrall to his emotions)
- A state of complete absorption
  (mountains holds us in thrall with 
  their attractions.)

It is evident that "thrall" is now a mass noun and functions in conjunction with the prepositions as situations demand as has been commented upon herein above. However, we can at best make a simple deduction that

- "IN THRALL TO" is a formal usage and goes to mean that one is completely overpowered by somebody or something.(She was in thrall to her abusive husband)
- IN THE THRALL OF  suggests a kind of subservience invited to which we are ready to yield to.(If you want to live along the lines, fall in the thrall of Federal Government.)

Collins Dictionary explains if you say that someone is in the thrall to a person or thing, you mean that they are completely in their power or are greatly influenced by them.=

[formal][+ to] He is not in thrall to media.≈[+of] Tomorrow's children will be even more in the thrall of silicon chip.

To sum up, the differences with change of prepositions (of, with,to) are minimal and therefore no hard and fast rule to adhere to. Both dictionaries one referred and one mentioned echo the same tone explained nicely by the learned commentators.